# how do i send a file response using FastAPI in Azure Functions?

Tags: python, azure, file, fastapi

I am having trouble sending a file response using Azure Functions and FastAPI. I am able to get this to work in my local environment but that's using my local directory and not a temp directory in Azure.

I have a Linux consumption plan - the code below is what I have been trying to push. it builds fine but calling the API from my browser doesn't generate the file on the client side as a download.

```py
@app.get("/get_csv", response_description='xlsx')
async def get_csv():
    Simulation_results = {'Fleet Size': [10,10], "Expected Yearly Demand":[10,10],"Actuals": 
    [10,10], "Service Level":[10,10]}
    df = pandas.DataFrame(data=Simulation_results)
    tempFilePath = tempfile.gettempdir()
    file_path = '/tmp/temp_excel.xlsx'
    df.to_excel(file_path, index = False)
    headers= {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.xlsx"'
    }  
    return FileResponse(file_path, headers=headers)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```

I'm not too sure what I am doing wrong and any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You never use `tempFilePath`, but you've hardcoded the temp file path - that path might not work on azure functions. Instead you should be able to use BytesIO to keep everything in memory and never need a temporary file: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO -- if you really need a temporary file, use the actual temporary files from `tempfile` (like SpooledTemporaryFile), not just the tempdir.

Comment: Thanks! that actually helped. i used gettempdir() to construct the file path and that worked out. correct code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was finally able to get it to work by constructing the file path from `tempfile.gettempdir()`

corrected code below:

```
@app.get("/get_csv", response_description='xlsx')
async def get_csv():

     headers= {
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.xlsx"'
     }
     Simulation_results = {'Fleet Size': [10,10], "Expected Yearly Demand": 
     [10,10],"Actuals":[10,10], "Service Level":[10,10]}


     df = pandas.DataFrame(data=Simulation_results)
  

     fp = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'temp.xlsx')
     df.to_excel(fp, index = False)


     return FileResponse(fp, headers=headers)




    def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return func.AsgiMiddleware(app).handle(req, context)
```